# Proving $r!$ divides the product of r succesive positive integers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction, divisibility, factorial

I have to prove the following theorem:

> Prove that the product of $r$ consecutive positive integers in divisible by $r!$

I am having a hard time getting a generalization down for the full set of real numbers, if I start from 1 and work up to r, I have the following:

$$r!k=\prod_{i=1}^{r}n_i$$

Can easily prove the base case of this, (n=1), and then go in to prove:

$$(r+1)!k=\prod_{i=1}^{r+1}n_i$$

Expand that out and get:

$$(r+1)r!k=n(n+1)(n+2).....(n+r)(n+r+1)$$

Can say that the product of the first $r$ elements in equal to $r!k$ by our base case. Leaving using with:

$$(r+1)k=(n+r+1)$$

Not sure where I can go from here, n is the integer that we start at, so how can I get it to work out to be equal to our induction hypothesis?

Comment: Hint: ${n+r\choose r}$ is an integer.

Comment: Full set of *real* numbers?  Divisibility is only interesting if we stick to the integers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this by simultaneous induction on $r$ and $n$.  Note that

$$\begin{align}
(n+1)\cdots(n+r)&=(n+1)\cdots(n+r-1)n\quad+\quad(n+1)\cdots(n+r-1)r\\
&=((n-1)+1)\cdots((n-1)+r)\quad+\quad(n+1)\cdots(n+(r-1))r
\end{align}$$

(I inserted a little extra space around the central plus signs to make the key pieces easier to see.)  By induction on $n$, $r!$ divides $((n-1)+1)\cdots((n-1)+r)$, and by induction on $r$, $(r-1)!$ divides $(n+1)\cdots(n+(r-1))$, hence $r!$ divides $(n+1)\cdots(n+(r-1))r$.

(Please note, I'm glossing over all the fine points of getting the inductions started.)

Comment: Sometimes induction doesn't need to be started. If $\forall n\in N  (\; [ \forall m\in N  \;(    m<n   \to  ( \psi (m)\;)   ] \;   \to \psi (n) \;)$    then $\forall n\in N\; (\psi (n).$

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$$
n\pars{n + 1}\ldots\pars{n + r - 1}={\pars{n + r -1}! \over \pars{n - 1}!}
={\pars{n + r -1}! \over \pars{n - 1}!r!}\,r! = {n + r - 1 \choose r}r!
$$

> $$
> {n\pars{n + 1}\ldots\pars{n + r - 1} \over r!} = {n + r - 1 \choose r}
> \quad\mbox{which is an integer !!!} 
> $$

Comment: Because it is the co-efficient of $x^r$ in the binomial expansion of $(1+x)^{n+r-1}.$

Comment: @Felix Martin  im sorry for commenting in your answer which is a year old.But i think you say it is divisible by r! becoz we get a integer as solution ,right?

Comment: @SathasivamK That's right.